# Open link to file in Vaadin

Tags: java, tomcat, hyperlink, vaadin

I'm trying to open a link to a file in a new window in Vaadin using the following code:

```
getWindow().open(new ExternalResource("./uploads/file.png"), "_blank");
```

I have the file stored in the webapp folder under /uploads/, hosted on a Tomcat server. But when I click the button which triggers the above code, a new window is opened with the previous window's content and with a URL pointing to the file, but no file download is triggered.

How do I open a link for downloading in a new window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, did you simply mean "../uploads/file.png"? (i.e. a resource outside the web application.)

You are using the [ExternalResource](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/application/application-resources.html), which basically means that you are opening a URL in the browser. The URL "./uploads/file.png" points to back to the application and you see the same window.

Instead you could be using [FileResource](https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/application/application-resources.html) to let the Vaadin application to serve the file. In this case, I suggest not to use relative paths as they may vary depending on the deployment server.

If you want to serve the file **directly** using Tomcat **in the same web application context** you should define in the web.xml that the "./uploads" does **not** map back to your application.

The easiest way to ensure this is to put the Vaadin application under "/application/*" (or similar) path. Without FileResource in the middle, this is more efficient approach.  Downside is that the application URI changes and that is visible to the users.

Comment: Ideally I want to serve images from the {application name}/WebContent folder, in the same web app context. FileResource seems to be working fine for files with an absolute path (e.g on the local file system), but how would I link to files in the WebContent folder?

Comment: Actually... it is probably a very silly idea to store dynamic files in the tomcat webapp folder. Absolute filepaths may just be the best solution here.

Comment: The WebContent folder would work fine as long as the context mapping for the application itself don't overlap. I've used separate /application/* and /resources/* mappings together with simple index.html that redirects the user to the real /application/ URI (just to avoid users to enter a shorter URL).